# Web Reference Name grayed out

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, ssrs-2008

I'm attempting to add an SSRS Web Reference to my existing C# MVC Web API using Visual Studio 2017 Professional. I click on Project, Add Service Reference, Advanced, Add Web Reference, enter the URL of the existing SSRS website and enter my credentials. I can view and even run the report in question but for some reason the Add Reference button is grayed out. How do I add this report as a Web Reference when it's grayed out like that?

[image]

**Update 1**

So with the help of Abhinaw Kaushik I was able to locate the WSDL file. However, when I browse to said file in the "Add Web Reference" window the Add Reference button is still greyed out. The SSRS server is a local server on my network. How do I get the "Add Reference" button to allow me to add this?

[image]

Comment: did you tried browsing the `url` you are trying to add? error says `discoveryError` also can you please give give the `URL` you are trying to add?

Comment: The URL is to our internally hosted SSRS website. It's not accessible by the outside world because it contains highly sensitive information. So this only work with public URLs?

Comment: That's fine, and that has nothign to do with private or public URLs; but are you able to brows that URL on your machine? is that generating WSDL document?

Comment: I can browse to it, yes. I am completely new to WSDL documents. Where would I find that?

Comment: put ?wsdl at the end of the .svc file url

Comment: Another stupid question: Where do I find the .svc file? I'm looking in the root directory of the SSRS website and I'm not seeing it. This is SSRS 08 R2 by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189472/discussion-between-abhinaw-kaushik-and-rhendar).